# How can I synchronize both google maps rendering and WebGL rendering to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The issue is when I'm moving on map or scrolling in/out, I want redraw to the canvas, but there is always a delay effect to the drawing due to the map rendering to be finished before the canvas redraw is done.

```
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 29.7789, lng: 15.8680},
    zoom: 15,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    let coordinates = map.getBounds().toJSON();
    boundMap(coordinates);
});
```

The problem comes from async nature, when new events are fired when moving/scrolling on map, the map is all fine and good but the queue has still some drawing tasks left to be done, and there is the annoying delay effect that objects are out of place for a moment.

I'm using 2 layers one above the other(z-index):

```
<div id="map"></div>
<canvas class="map"></canvas>
```

I'm drawing complex objects and I need to find an easy way that the new maps layer should be redrawn only and only when my canvas finished to be redrawn? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Parsing the coordinates data:

```
function boundMap(coordinates) {
    Data.bound.length = 0;
    for(let g = 0; g < Data.elements.length; g++) {
        if(Data.elements[g].checkBounds(coordinates)) {
            Data.bound.push(Data.elements[g]);
            Data.elements[g].clipCoordinates(coordinates);
        }
    }

    if(Data.bound.length !== 0)
        drawMap(gl);
    else {
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

And one simple prototype drawing function I use(without any requestAnimationFrame):

```
function drawMap(gl) {
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ...
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, Data.elements.length*12);
}
```

Comment: Then run code when your drawing method is through with its process. What are doing, rendering the map on some kind of mouse or touch movement?

Comment: Interest Q. Give more information about how you get images and how draws  function look like. I will try to give idea : Try to implement some fade in/out visual effect to bridge you delays...

Comment: @PHPglue and how can I manage to do it?

Comment: You should learn how to create Constructors, if you don't already know how. You should make drawing methods that can be easily reused. You should have a bunch of different modes you can set, that use the drawing methods. You should store the canvasContext, drawing method used, and coords into a State Object, which you should create for Undo, Redo, and Save. `onmouseup` is usually when your State should be set, run your map code then. If doing flood fills, use `ctx.getImageData()` and `ctx.putImageData()` when drawing to the canvas, as the process is intense.